# clion c++ debug shared library (.so) locally with source

Tags: c++, debugging, shared-libraries, clion, ros2

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 and use ROS2 Galactic.

I work in a project where all new Nodes are now LifecycleNodes instead of normal ones.
But I couldn't debug them which is really annoying.
They are always structured as a component (the logic itself) and a composition which is just a skeleton that launches the component. So when debugging I only had code insight to the composition, but not the relevant component. The component itself is compiled as an .so and included as a shared library. I noticed, that the composite node is using the component.so from the main_ws/install which is a release version. So building as Debug gives me access again:

"colcon build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug"

Because the composition when started will access the component.so from the main_workspace/install/node_name/ instead of the local generated one in the "cmake-build-debug" Folder within the src of the node.

I like it that way because then I only have to rebuild the node when I am finished. That way I can switch between the old and new version way faster in order to compare them.

How can I tell clion to use the component.so whithin the local debugging build instead of the main_ws/install which normally is a release version?

Answer (score 0):

Under "Run/Debug Configuration" you can look inside the current "Environmental variables". I think that are all the things sourced by the install/Setup.bash.
There is a "LD_LIBRARY_PATH". This can be edited. Look for your node and change the path to the one where the debugging .so is. I think it also works when adding the new path and leaving the old one there. This is way faster. I have 40 nodes in there so it takes some time to do this for every node ...

But now I can compile and debug from clion without manually building the main_ws/install as debug :)